# Negative Ricci curvature on the n-dimensional torus.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

The problem:

Let $T^n=\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ with arbitrary Riemannian metric $g$. Prove that there exists a point $p\in T^n$ and $v\in T_p T^n$ such that $\text{Ric}_p(v)\leq 0.$

My attempt:

By this corollary form do Carmos book Riemannian geometry

[image]

We get that for $n$ even, there is a point $p\in T^n$ where sectional curvature is not positive. And thus $$k(p)=\frac{1}{n}\sum \text{Ric}_p (X_i) <0,$$ for $\{X_i\}$ orthonormal basis in $T_p T^n.$

Is my answer in even dimension wrong? How can I solve the case of odd dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sectional curvature is not the right tool to use for this problem, because even if you have nonpositive sectional curvature on some $2$-planes at $p$ the averaging process in Ricci means it might end up being positive at $p$.  (Also, you confused the sectional curvature with scalar curvature, which is the average of Ricci.)

Assume $\operatorname{Ric}>0$ at every point.  Since $T^n$ is compact, we have $\operatorname{Ric}\geq\delta>0$ for some $\delta$.  This is preserved when we lift to the universal cover $\mathbb{R}^n$, but that contradicts Bonnet-Myer's diameter bound.

Comment: pff you are right but how do I compute the diameter of n-dimensional torus?

Comment: You don't.  You do it on the $\mathbb{R}^n$ which must have diameter $\infty$ (since the metric is complete).

Comment: Got you! Thanks a lot!

Comment: But do we have Ric $\ge 0$?